# Are deterministically unchangable Actions, and Funcs Inlined by the JIT?

Tags: c#, optimization, inline, compiler-optimization, jit

The title asks it all. We use actions, expressions with actions and callbacks quite extensively in today's code.

Can the JIT optimize these calls away by inlining them? This would be a huge performance boost, considering callback patterns, in one form or the other is used in absurd quantities today.

It is not possible for the JIT to optimize an action that might never change. For example, I don't see any reason why an Action or a Func, marked with "readonly" attribute shouldn't be optimized.

eg:

```
readonly Action a;
readonly Action a1;
readonly Action a2;

a = () => {};
a1 = () => { a() };
a2 = () => { a1() };
```

IS a2 ever optimized out? I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be.

Comment: No amount of wishful thinking is going to get that lambda body inlined.

Comment: Although the code can't be inlined, the C# compiler does optimize this by caching the delegate and re-using it for both calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non optimization itself is related to fact that it's not a function itself that matters, but the *code they execute*. You assign a `const` reference to action, but there is no any guarantee that the code executed by them is not mutable and/or is able produce *constant behavior*. If you can not guarantee, or predict somehow constant behavior, inlining usually is not a good idea, as you can have non predictable  execution flow, hence behavior, which is not something `.net framework` is targeting to.

In your concrete example, where we have simple, "dummy" functions, that may produce some inlining probably, but this looks to me like very special case, and highly unlikely to be happen in someone's code, so introduction of optimization in `.net framework` will have negligible benefit *for everyone*, hence, I guess, is not implemented in `CLR`.

**EDIT**

As was noted by @Sriram Sakthivel: the presence of a reflection in `.net runtime`, so *possible* and unpredictable runtime change of a function, is probably, one of the main disturbing factors here,in order to allow to the framework to determine either a given function is a good candidate for inlining or not.

Also, @hvd comment in @Sriram Sakthivel's answer, notes why a `readonly` keyword specifically simply cannot guarantee the deterministic immutability.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the reflection argument above makes sense. Supporting your answer of the action not leading to constant behavior. So, I guess it makes sense as to why it isn't in today's framework. But I wonder if the Action should just have a simple metadata like "sealed" potentially guaranteeing its immutability, be inlined. Because, as of today, technically the only possibility I see an Action not being deterministic is by meddling through reflection. Am I missing any other ways?

Comment: @PrasannaV.Loganathar: reflection makes many things more complicated. You are probably asking about C++ like `func() const` constant member functions, that are *guaranteed* to not change any member inside (if not there is a compile time error). but there is not such concept in .net

Comment: Got it. Would you mind amending your answer to @Sriram Sakthivel answer above so I can mark it? 

Both seem to have valid points and it seems to me that comparing this to virtual method calls doesn't seem accurate on its own, and your answer combined with comments on the above seem to be the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, Delegates cannot be optimized for the same reason [why virtual members cannot be](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx).

> - Virtual calls: We don't inline across virtual calls. The reason for not doing this is that we don't know the final target of the call. We
>     could potentially do better here (for example, if 99% of calls end up
>     in the same target, you can generate code that does a check on the
>     method table of the object the virtual call is going to execute on, if
>     it's not the 99% case, you do a call, else you just execute the
>     inlined code), but unlike the J language, most of the calls in the
>     primary languages we support, are not virtual, so we're not forced to
>     be so aggressive about optimizing this case.

Delegates can point to anything at runtime, so inlining isn't that easy. I know where you're coming from with the `readonly`, remember readonly isn't a silver bullet. Don't forget that reflection is more powerful than readonly, you could overwrite a readonly field with reflection. If the method was inlined, it will execute something else than what the delegate is pointing.

So, clearly JIT isn't going to inline your delegate calls.

**Update:** I've found an interesting article on the subject. [Can a Delegate Invocation be Inlined?](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2014/07/25/using-windbg-to-answer-implementation-questions-for-yourself-can-a-delegate-invocation-be-inlined/)

Comment: Ah, the reflection argument. I totally missed that. As of the moment, the problem is readonly is just a language specification, and CLR has nothing to do with it. 

Theoritically speaking, if a hypothetical 'sealed' keyword for Actions is provided, it can then be easily inlined, yes?

Comment: PS: I wouldn't compare this with virtual calls, since a sealed class implementation exists.

Comment: @PrasannaV.Loganathar `readonly` does also exist at the CIL level. However, making the runtime use that for optimisations is quite tricky, since any code *could* potentially be called from a constructor, where modifications of those readonly fields is still allowed. A separate keyword that indicates a field can be set only once, and then never modified, has many of the same problems: the code *using* that field might be in a constructor, or called from a constructor, before the value has been set.

Comment: Makes sense. So, I guess the inability to have strong deterministic single time modification guarantee makes it impossible to inline with the current specification. Thanks everyone!